# How to create a DBUS service

Tags: dbus

I am newbie to DBUS.

I have been trying to create a DBUS service for my program so that an application can contact it through DBUS.

I have gone through this tutorial http://kkaempf.blogspot.in/2009/03/d-bus-service-on-demand.html.

But as I go through this process and run qdbus command in linux, the service I had created is not listed on terminal.

So if somebody can list the procedure to create a DBUS service, it would be helpful.

Thanks,
Sathish

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything to be able to serve DBus messages. All clients and services exchange messages via bus, and bus is the only "server" - clients and services are "clients" here. Bus assigns name to a client automatically (it's usually ":some_number"). You can ask bus to assign your name with [RequestName](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusBus.html#ga8a9024c78c4ea89b6271f19dbc7861b2) message of org.freedesktop.DBus interface.

Note that if you want to request a name on system bus you need to add "allow own" policy to dbus config (see [example](https://github.com/sidorares/node-dbus/blob/master/examples/com.github.sidorares.dbus.Example.conf))